# Guincorn seems to be deleting Flask API data on each call

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I am facing this issue where when I call an endpoint to my API (built in Flask, running on gunicorn with 9 workers), the data loads the first time, then, when I refresh the page, it seems to throw the follow error:

```
{'message': 'Internal Server Error'}
```

For some detail, the API does not store anything in persistent data, it is stored in runtime/ram before a specific endpoint is called (in my case, localhost:8000/see/), which then frees** the ram by deleting said data.

** I have disabled the function to free up stored data so no matter how many times I refresh the page, it should show the data.

So, I am facing two issues:

1: I have an endpoint localhost:8000/data/ where I store information being sent to the server. When I call this endpoint with  that is inside of a dict, it should return all the data for that int. All data is shown at first, but when I refresh the page, it gives me the error I mentioned above. After a few refreshes of getting this error, the data shows up again but is gone on the next refresh.

2: When I call the /see/ endpoint, it should show me all the data I have collected, which it does but then when I refresh this page, it returns {} (disabled clearing, as mentioned above), which means the data is being cleared from runtime.

Furthermore, I have tried to fix this issue using the base Flask dev server, where I DO NOT encounter this error. I have also tried using another WSGI service: Waitress, which also does not give me these issues. I have tried running Gunicorn with supervisor and without, but I still am encountering these errors.

Any help would be appreciated as I would like to use Gunicorn. If there are good alternatives, please let me know.